# Running `sequence` over a conduit

Tags: haskell, conduit

I have a function of the effect:

```
f :: a -> Either b c
```

I want to build a conduit of this type:

```
ConduitT a c m (Maybe b)
```

Basically, we've got a stream of `a`s, and I want produce a stream of `c`s, but fail fast on error `b`.

If I was using lists, I'd be basically making a function

```
[a] -> Either b [c]
```

Which would be easy, just `sequence . (map f)`.

But I'm having trouble converting this to conduits. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, consider if you really want to *return* `Maybe b`, or if you want to raise the error in the monad `m`.  If the latter, then you may *actually* want:

```
mapMC :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> ConduitT a b m ()
```

which directly converts an `f :: a -> Either b c` to:

```
mapMC f :: ConduitT a c (Either b) ()
```

or for a more general `m` with an `ExceptT` transformer in the stack:

```
mapMC (liftEither . f) :: (MonadError b m) => ConduitT a c m ()
```

If you decide that, no, you really want a `Maybe b` return type, then the following will probably work:

```
import Conduit

whileRightC :: (Monad m) => (a -> Either b c) -> ConduitT a c m (Maybe b)
whileRightC f = mapAccumWhileC step Nothing
  where step a _ = case f a of Right c -> Right (Nothing, c)
                               Left  b -> Left  (Just b)
```

Alternatively, you can use the functions in `Data.Conduit.Lift` like so to convert a monadic exception generated by `mapMC` into an `Either` value that you can convert to a `Maybe`:

```
import Conduit
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except (except)

whileRightC :: (Monad m) => (a -> Either b c) -> ConduitT a c m (Maybe b)
whileRightC f = do
  r <- runExceptC $ mapMC (except . f)
  return $ case r of
    Left err -> Just err
    Right () -> Nothing
```

If performance is critical, you might want to benchmark these two versions of `whileRightC` to see which is faster.